# Как реализовать кнопку Назад в aiogram? НЕ ИНЛАЙН кнопка!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота, aiogram, как работает возврат на инлайн кнопках я понял. А вот как сделать это на обычной, в клавиатуре, понять не могу.
Кто сможет разжевать?...
Как Выходить из клавиатуры тоже понятно.

Но это все не то

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Выйти_из_клавы'))
async def some_func(msg: types.Message):
    reply_text = "Вышли из клавы"
    await msg.answer(reply_text,
reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы имели в виду под кнопкой "Назад"?

Comment: Допустим есть кнопка  "Одежда". Нажав на которую, перехожу в нужный раздел. Этот раздел состоит из нужных мне кнопок, так же под клавиатурой. И ниже всех остальных есть эта самая кнопка "Назад", при нажатии на которую, моя клавиатура сбрасывается и  возвращается обратно в раздел Где кнопка "Одежда".  Как бы на уровень назад.

Comment: @Greeshanka Используйте машину состояний, которая будет запоминать нажатие клавиш, после если было задано и обработалось конкретное состояние проверьте совпадает ли текст Кнопки назад, после выйдите с состояния и отправьте нужное вам сообщение..

Answer (score 1):

Нажатия на клавиатурные кнопки обычно подразумевают отправление текста с кнопки, почему бы не сделать из них связанную группу? Пример:

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Вернуться'))
async def some_func(msg: types.Message):
    reply_text = "Вернулись в начало"
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add('В меню')
    await msg.answer(reply_text, reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='В меню'))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add('Вернуться')
    await message.answer("Вот меню", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: ВЫ ГЕНИЙ! Как же не хотелось использовать машину состояний. Спасибо огромное